# CRTP override base class member function with minor change

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I want to extend my base class by adding some possible postprocessing or preprocessing in some important util functions, and at the same time, I want to ensure that, calls to base class member function invokes the overridden functions of the most derived class.

These two ideas are what I'm considering of;

1. Add `preprocess()` and `postprocess()` of derived class

```
  void func() {
    derived().func_pre();  
    // do the job of the base class
    derived().func_post();
  }
```

Truly awful, all derived class should implement `func_pre()` and `func_post()` even if they don't need.

2. Call `derived().func()` from `func()`

Base class:

```
   void func() {
       derived().func()
   }

   void func_impl() {
       // do the job of the base class 
   }
```

Derived class:

```
   void func() {
       preprocess();
       base().func_impl();
       postprocess();
   }
```

Better than idea 1, but `func()` will be ill-formed if there is no CRTP derived class.

Better ideas?

Comment: Using `1.` but with virtual functions; this negates the need to implement anything in the derived class. But the whole purpose of CRTP is to avoid virtual function dispatch. That only goes to show why CRTP never made sense to me, and always looked like an entry in buzzword bingo.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's good if you don't need the generality and flexibility of virtual functions.  If you do (as appears to be the case here), then it isn't.

Comment: You could declare and define an empty `preprocess` and `postprocess` function in the base class (both virtual). Derived classes can optional override these methods. What am I missing?

Comment: "all derived class should implement `func_pre()` and `func_post()` even if they don't need." I don't see why. The base class can provide default implementations (possibly empty). The derived class may choose to add its own, which would hide those in the base class. `derived().func_pre(); ` would then call the function in derived class if available, otherwise in the base class.

Comment: Or are you explicitly trying to come up with a design that doesn't depend on virtual functions. (static polymorphism)